# Java Enum Accepted Values

Tags: java, enums

An enum data type is defined as an attribute of a class.

```
public class Foo {

  public enum Direction {

    NORTH("north"),
    EAST("east"),
    SOUTH("south");

    public final String label;

    private Direction(String label) {
      this.label = label;
    }

  }

  private Directory direction;
  ...
}
```

When I parse a Json data to match the class, I get an error

```
String "east": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST]
```

This problem can be resolved by changing the enum data to all low case. If I want to use the Java enum data type convention, what is needed to resolve the problem?

Comment: Build an immutable map to look up the enum values by label (or easier but likely less efficient: loop over all enum values and compare the labels).

Comment: For enum normally deserialize mapping with enum values like `EAST` not it's level. You need to write a custom deserializer for enum to deserialize with lebels What you are using for json to class conversion Jackson ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Jackson to deserialise the Foo class, you could:

```kotlin
public class Foo {

  public enum Direction {

    NORTH("north"),
    EAST("east"),
    SOUTH("south");

    @JsonValue
    public final String label;

    private Direction(String label) {
      this.label = label;
    }

  }

  private Direction direction;
  // getter, setter for direction must exist
}

// then deserialise by:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"direction\":\"north\"}";
Foo f = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

This will result in a Foo object with a Direction.NORTH field.
For other possibilities when using Jackson check https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums

Comment: That works. Thanks. I am wondering how Gson handle this situation.

Comment: In Gson you can use the `@SerializedName` annotation which will have the same effect as `@JsonValue`. See https://memorynotfound.com/serializing-and-deserializing-enums-using-gson/

Comment: Tested and works for Jackson.